# How to use Keyboard with webview_flutter / JavascriptChannels with flutter_webview_plugin

Tags: android, ios, flutter, plugins, webview

I need to use a WebView in Flutter that uses the Keyboard but also i need to Communicate from the JS to Flutter.

I have used both webview_flutter and flutter_webview_plugin and looked at basically every other Question about this.

```
WebviewScaffold(
            allowFileURLs: true,
            withJavascript: true,
            withLocalStorage: true,
            withLocalUrl: true,
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("example"),
            ),
            url: new Uri.dataFromString(data, mimeType: 'text/html')
                .toString(),
          );
```

How would i either be able to use the Keyboard with webview_flutter or Communicate from the JS with flutter_webview_plugin ?

Edit: Solved with this https://github.com/rinlv/flutter_webview_plugin